# GoogleSignInAccount getIdToken() is null

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-signin

Hey I am using the **Firebase** auth and enabled the **Google login** feature.
The Google log in is working well and I get all informations. But when I want to save the user in the Firebase user-list the `getIdToken()` is null:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {       

    //here the acct.getIdToken() is null

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
      .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
          @Override
          public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
              if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                  Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Authentication failed.", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
              }

              // [START_EXCLUDE]
              progressDialog.hide();
              // [END_EXCLUDE]
          }
      });

}
```

Answer (score 28):

maybe you forgot to requestIdToken() on your GoogleSignInOptions object

try it:

```
GoogleSignInOptions gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DEFAULT_SIGN_IN)
                .requestIdToken(getString(R.string.default_web_client_id))
                .requestEmail()
                .build();
```

Answer (score 9):

Your Google OAuth client credential should be for Web Application, not Android. And your Google sign in options should look something like the code below (it's C# but quite close to the Java source):

```
var gso = new GoogleSignInOptions.Builder(GoogleSignInOptions.DefaultSignIn)
            .RequestIdToken("OAuth Client Id goes here")
            .Build();
```

It should work then.

Comment: Thanks, I literally spent 2 hours trying to solve this problem. Creating an OAuth client Id of Web Application type did the trick.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override `onActivityResult` method in your activity. Add this code:

```
if (requestCode == RC_SIGN_IN) {
        GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);
        if (result.isSuccess()) {
            GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
            firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);
        }
    }
```

And this how your `handleSignInResult` method should look like:

```
private void handleSignInResult(GoogleSignInResult result) {
    if (result.isSuccess()) {
        GoogleSignInAccount googleSignInAccount = result.getSignInAccount();
        if (googleSignInAccount != null) {
            String userId = googleSignInAccount.getId();
        }
        updateUI(true);
    } else {
        updateUI(false);
    }
}
```

You need also to enable in your `Firebase` account, in `Authentication` -> `SIGN-IN METHOD` -> `the provider`. You need to enable the one your are using, `Email/Password`, `Google` and so on.

You need also to put `compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:10.2.0'` in your `build.gradle` file.

In your AndroidManifest, you have to set this 2 permissions: `<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>' and '<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />`

You need also to set your SHA1. [Here](https://developers.google.com/drive/android/auth) you can take a look at how can be done. In the end, don't forget to put your google-services.json again in the right location.

And this how `firebaseAuthWithGoogle` method should look like:

```
private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    System.out.println("firebaseAuthWithGoogle:" + acct.getId());

    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    auth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    System.out.println("signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        System.out.println("signInWithCredential" + task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Authentication failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });
}
```

And very important, dont't forget to add this code in `onStart` method:

```
@Override
public void onStart() {
    super.onStart();

    OptionalPendingResult<GoogleSignInResult> optionalPendingResult = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.silentSignIn(googleApiClient);
    if (optionalPendingResult.isDone()) {
        GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult = optionalPendingResult.get();
        handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
    } else {
        optionalPendingResult.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<GoogleSignInResult>() {
            @Override
            public void onResult(@NonNull GoogleSignInResult googleSignInResult) {
                handleSignInResult(googleSignInResult);
            }
        });
    }
    auth.addAuthStateListener(authListener);
}
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

now you need to configure your project for adding facility of google signIn in your project here is the link
[enter link description here](https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/android/start-integrating)

Comment: Link only answers don't tend to do well. The goal is for an answer to be useful even if the link in it breaks.

Answer (score -1):

okay again my updated code:

```
private void signInGoogle(){
    Intent intent = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInIntent(googleSignInApi);
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQ_CODE);
}

...

@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    GoogleSignInResult result = Auth.GoogleSignInApi.getSignInResultFromIntent(data);

    if (requestCode == REQ_CODE){
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();
        handleResult(result);
    }
}

...


private void handleResult(GoogleSignInResult result){
    if (result.isSuccess()){

        // Google Sign In was successful, authenticate with Firebase
        GoogleSignInAccount account = result.getSignInAccount();

        String name = account.getDisplayName();
        String email = account.getEmail();

        googleProfilName.setText(name);
        googleProfilEmail.setText(email);

        if (account.getPhotoUrl() != null) {
            String img_url = account.getPhotoUrl().toString();
            Glide.with(this).load(img_url).into(profilPic);
        }

        String idTest = account.getId();

        firebaseAuthWithGoogle(account);

        updateUI(true);
    }
    else{
        updateUI(false);
    }
}

...



private void firebaseAuthWithGoogle(GoogleSignInAccount acct) {
    AuthCredential credential = GoogleAuthProvider.getCredential(acct.getIdToken(), null);
    firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(credential)
            .addOnCompleteListener(this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {
                    System.out.println("signInWithCredential:onComplete:" + task.isSuccessful());

                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        System.out.println("signInWithCredential" + task.getException());
                        Toast.makeText(SignIn.this, "Authentication failed.",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            });

}
```